# Django data from database don't show in site

Tags: django, jinja2, django-orm

Problem with show data in site in django from model

I try send the data from database, but nothing happend. Data don't show in site and console.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from .models import People
def Peoples(request):
    data = People.objects.all()
    peo = {
        "peo_login": data
    }
    print(peo)
    return render_to_response("templates/login.html", peo)
```

models.py

```
class People(models.Model):
    peo_login = models.CharField(db_column='PEO_LOGIN', primary_key=True, max_length=50)
    peo_name = models.CharField(db_column='PEO_IMIE', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

login.html

```
{% for Peopl in peo %}
<p>{{ Peoples.peo_login }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
    url(r'^login/$',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
```

I am newbie in Python, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write {{ Peopl.peo_login }} instead of {{ Peoples.peo_login }}. Also the url points to the template, it should point to the view 'Peoples' because it returns the template with the logic.

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me, what url I should create?

Comment: url('login/', views.Peoples), something like this